# Angular run loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

I was reading this blog:

http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/10/why-discourse-uses-emberjs.html

> The Run Loop
>
> One of the more complicated pieces of EmberJS is the run loop. Usually
>   you aren’t aware of it, but behind the scenes Ember batches up updates
>   to the DOM and bindings for performance. In some other frameworks if
>   you have a list of 100 items, and iterate through them changing them
>   all, you will end up with 100 separate DOM updates. Ember will batch
>   them and update all at once, providing a better user experience.

And it mentions this angular problem. Is this true? Are there any ways to mitigate this? From the sounds of it if this is the case then angular can be quite behind performance wise?

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS has something like a runloop too. The way they handle bindings is through the means of dirtychecking. A technique also used in (demanding) 3d videogames. The thought is that with this method AngularJS will be able to deliver a smooth experience with quick responsiveness (<50ms) for guis that contain up to 2000 elements (more would mean that your gui contains too much information in Angular opinion). That said, Angular will start making use of the Object.observe() functionality soon in newer browsers.

You can read here: 
http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/angularjs-10-12-roadmap.html

```
Object.observe() prototype (replace our dirty checking with O.o() )
```

This would mean that Angular will replace its dirty checking with what I believe to be optimal performance for this problem. The advantage is that you can use a less complex set-up (in EmberJS you have to use the Ember.set() and .get() method. Which won't be necessary anymore.

Your choice will come down to wanting to support older browsers (which EmberJS does), for the functionality of supporting big amounts of elements in the gui.

Comment: AngularJS doesn't batch DOM updates - which can be an issue for performance.